# Type 'Artem.Google.UI.GoogleMap' does not have a public property named 'GoogleMarkers'

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I am working on web site with ASP.NET and Google maps using visual studio 2012

I am trying to put a mark on map using this code

```
    <artem:GoogleMap id="GoogleMap1" runat="server" BackColor="White" Width="100%" Height="500px" Key="here I am using my key" 
    Latitude="33.512808" Longitude="36.292219" Zoom="13" EnableZoomControl="true" EnablePanControl="true" EnableScrollWheelZoom="false">

         <artem:GoogleMarkers runat="server" Latitude="33.512808" Longitude="36.292219">

         </artem:GoogleMarkers>

    </artem:GoogleMap>
```

but it is give me two errors

```
 Error  19  Type 'Artem.Google.UI.GoogleMap' does not have a public property named 'GoogleMarkers'.
 Error  20  Content ('</artem:GoogleMarkers>') does not match any properties within a 'Artem.Google.UI.GoogleMap', make sure it is well-formed.
```

and I have this code in web.config

```
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="artem" namespace="Artem.Google.UI" assembly="Artem.Google" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your markers in the code behind:

```
Dim objMarker As New Artem.Google.UI.Marker()
'objMarker.Icon.Url = "/images/marker.png"
objMarker.Position.Longitude = Longitude
objMarker.Position.Latitude = Latitude
objMarker.Info = "some html description"
Googlemap1.Markers.Add(objMarker)
```